# In Xamarin, are there downsides to using a Mutex with a Thread.Run?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, xamarin, thread-safety

I have been trying to cut down on having everything in the app run over the main/UI thread. I have done this because we are getting messages in the debugger about "doing too much work on its main thread". Then it would say x "number of frames skipped"
To fix this I read that I needed to do the following so that work wasn't done on the UI thread.

```
Task.Run(()=>{//my stuff});
```

I was worried that when I had code that accessed the Entity Framework context, another thread on a different view model might try to access the database at the same time, which would cause a crash. Another developer suggested that the following:

```
Task.Run(() => {
            Mutex m = new Mutex();
            m.WaitOne();
        using (var context = new VGSContext())
  

      {//database stuff} 
`    m.ReleaseMutex();
                });
```

I was wondering how this code makes it so other threads in different viewmodels can't access the database. Does it make a single thread run at a time? If so, will that slow down performance? I was wondering about any other issues could happen because I used a mutex.

Comment: Can you even use a Mutex in Xamarin? I'm not sure what you expect that Mutex in your code example to do, but if the code in that Task isn't shared with other threads and none have access to that mutex, either local or global then you're only wasting OS resources.

Comment: I'm also not sure how "too many threads" get resolved by making more threads. Maybe a Queue with commands in it and a single worker thread to handle these would be more what I would expect.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what's a "frame" (of which you have too many) in this context? I hear "frame" and I'm thinking steps in an animation, and more frames would be better because it would be smoother (less change per frame).

Comment: Use a backgroundworker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-8.0 and just make sure that your dbcontext instance doesn't get shared across threads.

Comment: I haven't found what the frame actually is but I found out the following: "When you encounter the message “Skipped XX frames!” in the Xamarin debugger, it indicates that your application may be performing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: That sounds more like "not enough frames" if it's having to skip them.

Comment: You shouldn't use any thread other than the UI thread when doing anything with the UI - including view models. You can only push non-UI work to other threads.